# Importance of boundedness of classical operators of harmonic analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Boundedness of classical operators of harmonic analysis, such as maximal
functions, fractional integrals and singular integrals have been extensively investigated in various function spaces. For example, we know that Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator $M$ is bounded from Lebesgue space $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $p>1$ and from $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to weak Lebesgue space $WL^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$; Riesz potential $I_{\alpha},~0<\alpha<n$ is bounded from $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $1<p<\frac{n}{\alpha}$ and $q=\frac{np}{n-\alpha p}$ and from $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $WL^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $q=\frac{n}{n-\alpha}$; Calderon-Zygmund operator $T$ is bounded from $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $p>1$ and from $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $WL^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. These results are classical and can be found many textbook. These results have been extended to many other function spaces such as Morrey space, Lorentz space, Orlicz space etc, which are generalizations of Lebesgue space.

My question is: Where do we use these results? What is the advantage of these results? What is the importance of these operators? Could you give me concrete examples?

Comment: One example, boundedness of the maximal function is used to prove the Lebesque differentiation theorem and the ergodic theorem.

Comment: They use them to study existence and uniqueness of solutions to PDE.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith could you give me a reference book for this fact.

Comment: Google "harmonic analysis and partial differential equations".  Unfortunately most of the hits will be conference proceedings, and hence rather advanced.  But it will give you a good idea of the strength of the connection.